# Python regular expression that replaces test before a particular pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to create a regular expression in python that does the following:

In line "/home/python/app/index.html", it searches for anything that comes before 'app' and removes that text i.e. in this case returns me "app/index.html."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Furthermore, please define your problem more precisely. For example, I expect that you wouldn't want `/home/apple/app/index.html` to become `apple/app/index.html`, right?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I want /home/apple/app/index.html to become app/index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use 'groups' in you regexp, like so:

```
>>> s = re.search(r".*\/(app.*)", "/home/python/app/index.html")
>>> s.groups()[0]
'app/index.html'
```

Note that in this regexp, there's exactly one group -- which is 'app' followed by the rest of the string - but not just any 'app', only one preceded by a slash. Note that the slash is NOT included in the round brackets - hence not in the group (per your question looks like that's what you want).

Comment: Yes, very thanks. That's exactly what I wanted. I am new to python, can you please explain in short what does this mean ".*\/(app.*)" in short. I will be thankfull.

Comment: 1. 're' is the name of the module containing regular expressions logic/support 2. 'search' is the function to attempt to find the regexp in the string. 3. regexp is the first argument - in this case, 'r".*\/(app.*)", "/home/python/app/index.html"'. This is how it reads: "regexp, which start with any character repeated any number of times (this is what '.*' means). Then there must be a forward slash (this is what '\/' means), and then followed by a group, which is itself made of 'app' followed, again, by any number of any characters.

Comment: here is the link explaining what exactly _re.search_ function does: [re.search](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search)

Comment: Thank you alexakarpov. You made it very easy. One last question, where can I get information about making 'group'.

Comment: To understand groups you should read the official documentation: [Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). Group is a part of a regexp enclosed in round brackets, e.g. in the regexp above the group is `(app.*)`. You can have more than one group - in which case, after attempting a match with functions like 'search' or 'match', you will be able to retrieve any of the groups -- in our case, there was only one group, so we accessed it with s.groups[0].  PS: if you found my answer helpful, please make sure to *accept* the answer =) Cheers.

Comment: Yes, both your answer and explanations are perfect. thanks.